# run launch4j on macos

Tags: java, jar, exe, launch4j

I want to turn my .jar file into an .exe file on my macOS. I use launch4j, but the 'JRE paths' configuration is always wrong, and it always says
`103 RCDATA BEGIN "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment\0" END`
`104 RCDATA BEGIN "The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Runtime Environment installation or the runtime is corrupted.\0" END`
`net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/launch4j/3.50/libexec/bin/windres": error=2, No such file or directory`

I've tried`%JAVA_HOME%` `$JAVA_HOME` `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home` `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/` `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk`.etc, none of these work.
Could you tell me what's wrong?

The launch4j is version 3.5.

added:
I add the file `windres` in `/usr/local/Cellar/launch4j/3.50/libexec/bin/windres`, but it says `net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/launch4j/3.50/libexec/bin/windres": error=13, Permission denied`

Comment: `error=2, No such file or directory` means the file/program `/usr/local/Cellar/launch4j/3.50/libexec/bin/windres` does not exists in the machine.

Comment: reply to@Karthikeyan: I add the file `windres` in `/usr/local/Cellar/launch4j/3.50/libexec/bin/windres`, but it says `net.sf.launch4j.ExecException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/Cellar/launch4j/3.50/libexec/bin/windres": error=13, Permission denied`

Comment: `error=13, Permission denied` means the user do not have permission to execute the file `/usr/local/Cellar/launch4j/3.50/libexec/bin/windres`. How did you add the file? are using homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

1. Run *launch4j.jar:*

```bash
sudo java -jar launch4j.jar
```

2. If you face some error like *permission denied* or *not allowed developer's app*

**Check this side: You may need to allow every time you see a launch4j error message.**

1. [System Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raSCz.png)
2. [Private ~~ Secure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sk0B.png)
3. [Allow Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SDvQ.png)